# Shell script loop, increment by hex

Tags: shell

```
for num in {3758145536..3758149632..4}
do
    echo "obase=16; $num" | hexnum
    peek -lt $hexnum > "/luascript/dumpfileA"
done
```

What I want to do is, iterate from address0xe000000 to 0xe0001000
Use peek to peek these section memory and write result to file.

SO I use Deceimal to do increment job. Then convert to Hex.

Maybe ,can I increment by Hex directly?

But this is not working .
Need help
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I'll assume you are using bash).

In general, bash only allows you to enter numeric literals in base 10. You can use other bases in arithmetic contexts (inside `((...))`, for example), but it will be displayed in its base-10 representation. You can use the `printf` built-in to convert quickly to a hexadecimal representation, however.

```
for (( num=0xe0000000; num <= 0xe0001000; num+=4 )); do
    peek -lt $( printf "%x" $num ) >> /luascript/dumpfileA
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `zsh` you can do something like this (note `c_bases` needs to be set to get `0x` in front of `$num`):

```
setopt c_bases
typeset -i 16 num
for num in $( seq $((0xe000c000)) 4 $((0xe000d000)) ); do 
  echo "peek -lt $num > /luascript/dumpfileA"
done | head
```

Output:

```
peek -lt 0xE000C000 > /luascript/dumpfileA
peek -lt 0xE000C004 > /luascript/dumpfileA
peek -lt 0xE000C008 > /luascript/dumpfileA
peek -lt 0xE000C00C > /luascript/dumpfileA
peek -lt 0xE000C010 > /luascript/dumpfileA
peek -lt 0xE000C014 > /luascript/dumpfileA
peek -lt 0xE000C018 > /luascript/dumpfileA
peek -lt 0xE000C01C > /luascript/dumpfileA
peek -lt 0xE000C020 > /luascript/dumpfileA
peek -lt 0xE000C024 > /luascript/dumpfileA
```

Remove `head`, `echo` and the quoting when you're happy with the output.

Comment: Will `peek` understand an argument in the form of "16#E000D170"? (I'm adding this to my list of reasons to learn zsh, though.)

Comment: @chepner: I should have been more explicit, if the `c_bases` option is set the base is output as `0x`, I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

So simple!  Use this:

```
bc <<< "obase = 16 ; $(seq 0 65536)"
```

Comment: Your answer is showing up in the Low Quality Posts review list. I suggest fleshing it out with a bit of explanation.